# A template to bring the CMD window to the foreground while executing any Python code

Tags: python, cmd

When I want to bring VSCode to the foreground by running any Python in the terminal, I do it this way:

```python
import subprocess
import os

VS_CODE_PATH = r'C:\Users\Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe'

def attention() -> None:
    subprocess.Popen([VS_CODE_PATH, os.getcwd()])
```

I tried directly using the path to CMD:

```python
import subprocess
import os

CMD_PATH = r'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe'

def attention() -> None:
    subprocess.Popen([CMD_PATH, os.getcwd()])
```

But it didn't bring what's running to the foreground as I wanted.

How should I proceed so that he can perform this desired action for me?

Answer (score 0):

To bring window to foreground you can use [PyGetWindow](https://github.com/asweigart/PyGetWindow). This script should work on any OS because **PyGetWindow** library is cross-platform. I've tested it on windows 11. I've added ".*?" to regex statement, because VS Code inclues name of file and name of project on to title. Also, if you have multiple VS Code instances runing in the same time, you shoud modify this script accordingly.

```
import pygetwindow as gw
from re import match


def bring_window_to_foreground(window_title):
    windows = gw.getAllTitles()
    filtered_values = list(filter(lambda v: match(f".*?{window_title}.*?", v), windows))
    win = gw.getWindowsWithTitle(filtered_values[0])[0]
    win.activate()
    
bring_window_to_foreground("Visual Studio Code")
```

Comment: Hello Anytokin, in my case, to bring VSCode to foreground, I use the first code, it works perfectly. The problem is when I run Python directly in CMD, without open Terminal in VSCode, I want it to be placed in the foreground even if there are several Python's running in different CMD's.